# What is the use of constructor chaining within the same class?

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor, this

Consider the following snippet

```
private XYZOuputStream(String prodid, String productname) {
    this.productid = prodid;
    this.productname = (productname == null) ? DEFAULT_PRODUCT_NAME : productname;
}

private XYZOuputStream(String productid, String path, String productname, String password) throws Exception {
    this(productid, productname);
    this.filepath = path;
    this.password = password;
    initClient();
}

public XYZOuputStream(String productid, String password, String path, String productname, boolean overwrite, boolean iscompressed) throws Exception {
    this(productid, path, productname, password);
    this.overwrite = overwrite;
    this.iscompressed = iscompressed;
    initOuputStream();
}
private void initClient() throws Exception {
    this.dbClient = clientPool.getClient(this.productid, this.productname);     
}
```

Where I am invoking the constructor within the same class.

Have read somewhere that

```
public constructor_name(String name) {
    this.test_name = name;
    System.out.println("Name printed is :::"+ this.test_name);
}
```

The above use of `this.name` would cause trouble, Since the object creation is not completed yet.

Please clarify me the following:

1. Will this use of `this.name` cause trouble because the object has not been created yet? and
2. Does the above way of invoking constructor within constructor is correct way of doing? (ie; am I using the constructor chaining within the same class in the right sense?)

I am not sure whether I can post it here since it is to get clarity on a concept and not programming :-(

Comment: I think your chains are the wrong way round: the ctors with fewer parameters should be calling the ones with more, providing default values for the missing parameters.

Comment: "The above use of this.name would cause trouble" the main trouble here is that you are overwriting the parameter.

Comment: I am doing it because i need to use the object values (say x,y,z). x and y are initialized within constructor and i need to initialize z with the help of x and y. Please correct me if am understanding it in the wrong sense...

Comment: There is no such thing as constructor chaining **other** than within the same class. Your question is meaningless.

Comment: @EJP There is chaining with superclass ctors too, which is what I suspect OP was thinking about as "non-same class chaining".

Comment: **Builder Pattern**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will this use of `this.name` cause trouble because the object has not been created yet?

```
public constructor_name(String name) {
    name = "Rabbit";
    System.out.println("Name printed is :::"+ this.name);
}
```

**1)** It may cause logic errors in your code. When `System.out.println` is invoked, it will **not** use parameter `name` with value of `Rabbit` but `this.name` which is class field. So it will print whatever value it has. If the field has been initialized with other than default value, for example `String name = "Bird";`, it will print `Bird`, otherwise `null` will be printed. **NOTE!** If superclass has field `name` and subclass doesn't override it, then even if you refer with keyword `this`, the superclass `name` will be used.

**2)** Also this constructor with parameter `name` in his signature doesn't make any sense. Because in its body you reassigning its value to `"Rabbit"`, so there is no point of passing anything, then `public constructor_name()` would be much better choice.

**3)** If you need to initialize a field based on other fields then, do like this

```
public constructor_name(String x, String y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = x + y; // or this.z = this.x + this.y;
    System.out.println("Sum is :::"+ this.z);
}
```

> Does the above way of invoking constructor within constructor is correct way of doing?

No, it is not. A class should have only one primary constructor. Other constructors should call primary constructor. But in your example each constructor calls different constructor (one parameter extra).

To fix this let's declare your primary constructor

```
public XYZOuputStream(String productid, String password, String path, String    productname, boolean overwrite, boolean iscompressed) throws Exception {
    this.productid = productid;
    this.path = path;
    this.productname = (productname == null) ? DEFAULT_PRODUCT_NAME :    productname;
    this.password = password;
    this.overwrite = overwrite;
    this.iscompressed = iscompressed;
    // if(someCondition) for example path != null call initOutputStream();
    // initOuputStream();
```

}

Then all other constructors will call it.

```
private XYZOuputStream(String productid, String path, String productname,   String password) throws Exception {
    this(productid, password, path, productname, false, false)
    initClient();
}

private XYZOuputStream(String productid, String productname) throws Exception {
    this(productid, DEFAULT_PASSWORD, DEFAULT_PATH, productname, false, false)
}
```

**NOTE!** you need to provide default arguments for main constructor which doesn't have corresponding parameter in containing constructor for example `boolean overwrite` parameter gets `false` argument.

Comment: Consider where i need to initialize `product_package` variable of my object with the help of `productname`. Can this be done like `this.product_package` = `this.productname`+"package" will this cause any trouble of doing so? Please help me with this..

Comment: If the `this.productname` has value, then it will not. But make sure that you initialize `this.productname = name;` first, before calling `this.product_package = this.productname + "package";` in constructor. Otherwise do like this `this.product_package = name + "package";`

Comment: yeah Dennis Grinch.... I would initialize it prior to `this.product_package`.. But in my case `this.productname` would have some computations which i wish it need not be repeated for initializing to product_package variable too..